# generating xml from PHP with tags

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to generate the following xml code using php:

http://dpaste.com/708476 (now broken)

I tried to do this in many several ways, but why is the output always without any tags ????
i want it to be the same exact format as he xml file and with all the tags ...
here is what i get when i tried to output it:

```
2 834 SE LAMBERT CIRCLE 45.490943 -122.406561 834 SE LAMBERT ST 45.468602 -122.657627
```

Does anyone have any idea what should I do?

Comment: Dont look at it in the browser where the tags get evaluated. Right click > View Source.

Comment: it depends on how you're displaying the result. it could already be xml and you're just not displaying it in a way that you can see the tags. when you print it out in the browser view the source code.

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more on what approaches you've tried. Are you writing the XML strings by hand? Are you using one of the PHP XML libraries, like XMLWriter[1]? Or a third party library?

[1] http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php

Comment: If you aren't outputting HTML from PHP make sure you set the correct content-type using the `header()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are outputting the first line in an echo statement or similar:

```
<?php
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";
?>
//rest of XML
```

If you just have `<?xml...` (outside of PHP tags) as the first line, PHP will think you are trying to use an (undefined) constant `xml`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php header('Content-type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8'); ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<geocoderResults>
  <count>2</count>
  <results>
    <result>
      <description>834 SE LAMBERT CIRCLE</description>
      <lat>45.490943</lat>
      <lng>-122.406561</lng>
    </result>
    <result>
      <description>834 SE LAMBERT ST</description>
      <lat>45.468602</lat>
      <lng>-122.657627</lng>
    </result>
  </results>
</geocoderResults>
```

Comment: Why even bother with the huge 'echo'? This is a perfect candidate for a heredoc, or better yet, just breaking out of php mode after the header call and just having the raw xml.